# Google Drive Rest API - How to check if file has changed

Tags: google-drive-api

**Is there a reliable way, short of comparing full contents, of checking if a file was updated/change in Drive?**

I have been struggling with this for a bit. Here's the two things I have tried:

**1. File `version` number**

I upload a plain text file to Google Drive ([simple upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/simple-upload), [update endpoint](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)), and save the `version` from the [file metadata](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) returned after a successful upload.

Then I poll the Drive API ([get endpoint](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)) occasionally to check if the version has changed.

The trouble is that within a second or two of uploading the file, the version gets bumped up again.

There are no changes to the file content. The file has not been opened, viewed, or even downloaded anywhere else. Still, the version number increases from what it was after the upload.

To my code this version number change indicates that the remote file has been changed in Drive, so it downloads the new version. Every time!

**2. The `Changes` endpoints**

As an alternative I tried using the [Changes api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-changes).

After I upload the file, I get a `page token` using [`changes.getStartPageToken`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/getStartPageToken) or [`changes.list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/list).

Later I use this `page token` to poll the Changes API for changes, and filter the changes for the fileId of uploaded file. I use these options when polling for changes:

```
{
    "includeRemoved": false
    "restrictToMyDrive": true
    "spaces": "drive"
}
```

Here again, there is the same problem as with the version number. The page token returned immediately after uploading the file changes again within a second or two. The new page token shows the uploaded file having been changed.

Again, there is no change to the content of the file. It hasn't been opened, updated, downloaded anywhere else. It isn't shared with anyone else.

Yet, a few seconds after uploading, the file reappears in the changes list.

As a result, the local code redownloads the file from Drive, assuming remote changes.

---

**Possible workaround**

As a hacky hook, I could wait a few seconds after the file upload before getting the new file-version/changes-page-token. This may take care of the delayed version increment issue.

However, there is no documentation of what is causing this phantom change in version number (or changes.list). So, I have no sure way of knowing:

1. How long a wait is safe enough to get a 'settled' version number without losing possible changes by other users/apps?
2. Whether the new (delayed) version number will be stable, or may change again at any time for no reason?

---

**Is there a reliable way, short of comparing full contents, of checking if a file was updated/change in Drive?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using the `md5Checksum` property of the [File resource object](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files), if your file is not a Google Doc file (ie. binary). You should be able to use that to track changes to the contents of your binary files.

You might also be able to use the [Revisions API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-revisions).

The [Revisions resource object](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions) also has a `md5Checksum` property.

Comment: Thanks! Already tried that, but forgot to mention in the post above.

I think the Revisions API is only for Google Docs, Sheets and Slides.

The revisions API returns 404 when I attempt to [`list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list) revisions of the file - it's a plain text file.

Comment: @AdiB Did you try the `md5Checksum` property in the [File resource object](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) or the [Revision resource object](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions)?.

Comment: Thanks! I missed the `md5Checksum` property in `File` resource. Will test that out. Hopefully it should stay stable if the contents aren't changing.

Comment: Thanks @dimu-designs. A combination of file `version` and `md5Checksum` worked well in detecting remote file changes.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, how about using Drive Activity API? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

When Drive Activity API is used, the activity information about the target file can be retrieved. For example, from [ActionDetail](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/actiondetail#ActionDetail), you can see whether the target file was edited, renamed, deleted and so on.

The sample endpoint and request body are as follows.

#### Endpoint:

```
POST https://driveactivity.googleapis.com/v2/activity:query?fields=activities%2CnextPageToken
```

#### Request body:

```
{"itemName": "items/### fileId of target file ###"}
```

#### Response:

Sample response is as follows. You can see the information from this. The file with the fileId and filename was edited at the timestamp.

```
{
  "activities": [
    {
      "primaryActionDetail": {
        "edit": {}  <--- If the target file was edited, this property is added.
      },
      "actors": [
        {
          "user": {
            "knownUser": {
              "personName": "people/### userId who edited the target file ###",
              "isCurrentUser": true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "actions": [
        {
          "detail": {
            "edit": {}
          }
        }
      ],
      "targets": [
        {
          "driveItem": {
            "name": "items/### fileId of target file ###",
            "title": "### filename of target file ###",
            "file": {},
            "mimeType": "### mimeType of target file ###",
            "owner": {
              "user": {
                "knownUser": {
                  "personName": "people/### owner's userId ###",
                  "isCurrentUser": true
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "timestamp": "2000-01-01T00:00:0.000Z"
    },
  ],
  "nextPageToken": "###"
}
```

#### Note:

- When you use this API in my environment, please enable Drive Activity API at API console and include `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity.readonly` in the scopes.
- Although when I used this API, I felt that the response was fast, if the response was slow when you use this, I apologize.

#### References:

- [Google Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/)
- [ActionDetail](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/actiondetail#ActionDetail)

If this was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to resolve the issue using a combination of checksum and version number.
The activity API may have worked, but I didn't get to try it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the eventual consistency feature of the Google Drive filesystem. If you think about search, it doesn't matter how quickly a search index is updated, only that it is eventually updated and is very efficient for reading. Google Drive works on the same premise.

Drive acknowledges your updates as quickly as possible. Long before those updates have propagated to all worldwide copies of your file. Derived data (eg. timestamps and I think I recall, md5sums) are also calculated after the update has "completed".

The solution largely depends on how problematic the redundant syncs are to your app.

- The delay of a few seconds is enough to deal with the vast majority of phantom updates.
- You could switch to the v2 API and use etags.
- You could implement your own version number using custom properties. So every time you sync up, you increment your own version number. You only sync down if the application version number has changed.

Comment: Thanks! The redundant syncs were quite problematic, hence the cry for help. Also, since it's an open file format, I couldn't add custom version properties to it.

Adding a 2 sec delay before fetching version worked as a solution, but I just wasn't comfortable with it. There's no documented/suggested delay, so there's no guarantee it wouldn't break.

Using a combination of `version` and `md5Checksum` - suggested above - resolved the issue, and I was able to remove the delay.

Comment: Cool. As I said, I seem to recall that the md5sum property is set asynchronously, so there may be times when the 2s isn't enough, eg when Google data centres have elevated latency issues. So you'll still need some additional anti sync storm check for that scenario.