# Last revision always showing the same user in Google App Scripts Drive.Revisions.list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to get an accurate update of when a Google Sheets file is modified.

All the dates on the main file seem to be cached by Google, the only date I have found to be accurate is the last revision date - Please correct me if I am wrong!?

This is great, however it is always showing the sheet owner in the `revision.lastModifyingUser.emailAddress` field, rather than the actual user that has done the modification.

Can anyone help with how I can get a correct and accurate date and user of the last modified date of the Google Sheet?  Is there a way I can force the Google Sheets API to clear the cash perhaps to give me the correct dates and users?  Or is there a way to get the user correctly from the revisions list as per the below code?

```
  var fileId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId);
  var revisionLength = revisions.items.length;

  if (revisionLength > 0) {
    var revision = revisions.items[revisionLength - 1];
    console.log(revision.modifiedDate + ' - ' + revision.lastModifyingUser.emailAddress);
  }
```

Comment: Seems like a use case for the Drive Activity API: https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/ The Sheets API is for reading & writing to Google Sheets, not enforcing a traceability requirement you may have.

Comment: This sounds interesting, I will take a look. Can this integrate with Google App Scripts?

Comment: @user3284707 Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54797416